# Within IntelliJ IDE the java file.exists() always returns false

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-7-x64, java-io

In intelliJ I have this simple program that only checks if the file exists

```
File myFile=new File("myFile.txt");
boolean isExists=myFile.exists();
```

The isExists is always false.

If I try

```
  FileInputStream stream=new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

it throws a file not found exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I verified that IntelliJ was running as the myself, that is as an administrator ( I verified using sysinternal tools)

But if I run the compiled class file from command prompt, it works.

I also tried reading the contents of the file, which too works from the command prompt.

Is this a bug in intellij?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. You need to check the run configuration settings and make sure that the working directory is set to the same directory as the one that you use when running from the command line.